# Does the CDMA iPhone 4S support simultaneous voice and data on Verizon

Tags: iphone, cdma

I [read](http://www.cultofmac.com/76612/verizon-iphone-cant-do-simultaneous-voice-and-data-like-every-other-cdma-phone/) that the iPhone 4 couldn't do this. Is that still true of the 4S when used in CDMA?

As @Jannemans points out this wasn't possible in any CDMA phone until one point. But the question is valid now that the CDMA standard allows it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1976), "CDMA networks do not support simultaneous voice and data over any connection."

I tried this with a Sprint phone, it didn't work. It gives an error message when you try to surf the web when on a call. However WiFi data still works.

Comment: Why the down vote? It answers a question.

Comment: I'd downvoted your original answer because it was wrong. I've now rescinded the vote as your answer is now correct.

Answer (score 4):

The limitation of simultaneous voice and data is not one of the iPhone but one related to the CDMA2000 standard.

However, the official CDMA Development group announced the CMDA X standard on Aug 17 2009. This standard allows for simultaneous voice and data:

Quoting the [press release](http://www.cdg.org/news/press/2009/Aug17_09.asp)

*A complementary device enhancement known as simultaneous 1X Voice and EV-DO Data (SVDO) will also become available during the same timeframe and will enable CDMA2000 devices to access EV-DO packet data services while in an active 1X circuit-switch voice call. For example, users will be able to send emails or access the Web while on voice calls; phones with GPS can update maps or download real-time traffic information while on voice calls, etc. This device enhancement, which enables these concurrent voice and data services, is independent of the air link standard and infrastructure.*

When Verizon or any other CDMA carrier will implement this, is an entirely different question...

Comment: Does the 4S support SVDO? Is SVDO interoperable with any CDMA2000 chipset, or do they need to support that in hardware as well as baseband software?