# Does the iPhone 5 support simultaneous voice and data on CDMA

Tags: data, cdma, voice, iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will the Verizon iPhone 5 be capable of accessing cellular data while on an active phone call?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/63936/will-the-verizon-iphone-5-be-capable-of-accessing-cellular-data-while-on-an-acti)

I asked [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27254/does-the-cdma-iphone-4s-support-simultaneous-voice-and-data-on-verizon) for the iPhone 4S. Now that the iPhone 5 is announced, will it do simultaneous voice and data on CDMA (not data on WiFi)?

Comment: Unsure, so I don't want to make this an answer, but I think the limitation is in the CDMA protocol - my BlackBerry terminates Data when a voice call comes. I think it can **not** do simultaneous voice/data due to CDMA.

Comment: @Rich Homolka, As mentioned by Jannemans' answer to the previous question, the CDMA x standard does allow this now. I don't know if any phones support this, however.

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/63938/115

Comment: Was asked before 63938. That is a duplicate of this.